# Django SQL query for each include/extends

Tags: sql, django

I'm using Django to realize a engineering management system. I've made something really wrong somewhere, and my SQL query count is very high on some pages.

For example, I got 95 to 98 SQL queries in a single page, a simple ListView. All the queries are the same :

```
SELECT * FROM "syncoor_codification" LIMIT 21
```

They always return the same object. I suspect the queries to be triggered by my model's get_queryset() function.

If I use Django Debug Toolbar, I can see that the queries are triggered inside the template, by lines like :

```
{% extends 'syncoor/base.html' %}
{% extends 'syncoor/docs/base.html' %}
{% extends 'syncoor/docs/codifications/base.html' %}
{% include 'syncoor/js/jsp.js' %}
```

How could I get rid of this extra overhead ?

**Edit :** here's a screenshot :

[image: Query triggered for CSS file]

Comment: Do you know where the `LIMIT 21` comes from? When you print querysets,  like `print MyModel.objects.all()` it doesn't print all the results because it automatically limits the request to 21 for comfort purpose. So my guess is that you have somewhere some useless `print` that trigger those requests with `LIMIT 21`. I don't know why they're triggered by the `include` and `extends`, though.

Comment: Please post template and view source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the picture you posted, the stack trace shows 2 things of note.

1. The SQL calls are being performed inside a signal handler associated with django-debug-toolbar, specifically the TEMPLATE panel.
2. The SQL call has it's limit clause set to REPR_OUTPUT_SIZE, Indicating that the template panel is trying to render a representation of a queryset.

This leads me to believe that you have passed a function or lazy object that returns a new queryset into the context at some point and it is this object that is being evaluated by the template panel. See if you can spot a bunch of Entity Objects in the context in the templates panel.

To confirm, try setting your settings like this.

```
DEBUG_TOOLBAR_PANELS = (
    'debug_toolbar.panels.version.VersionDebugPanel',
    'debug_toolbar.panels.timer.TimerDebugPanel',
    'debug_toolbar.panels.settings_vars.SettingsVarsDebugPanel',
    'debug_toolbar.panels.headers.HeaderDebugPanel',
    'debug_toolbar.panels.request_vars.RequestVarsDebugPanel',
   # 'debug_toolbar.panels.template.TemplateDebugPanel',
    'debug_toolbar.panels.sql.SQLDebugPanel',
    'debug_toolbar.panels.signals.SignalDebugPanel',
    'debug_toolbar.panels.logger.LoggingPanel',
)
```

Comment: I must learn to pay more attention to stack traces... django-debug-toolbar was indeed issuing queries each time it had to render the context for a template. many thanks :)

Answer (score -1):

It looks like there are loops running in your `base.html` templates that are hitting the database. That's why inheriting from those templates is generating queries. Without seeing the templates themselves it's hard to say what the exact problem is, but that's certainly where you'll find the answer.

Comment: Django Debug Toolbar also reports queries triggered by empty template ! And files like 'syncoor/js/jsp.js' do not contain any template code

Comment: I just tried to follow your link but it was blocked by my office network as 'adult content'! Could you post your debug information direct to SO instead please.

Comment: I added the picture to my base post

Comment: Can you post the whole stack trace part of which is visible on the screenshot?